# How would i correct this so that it doesn't fetch more than one record?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, triggers, procedure

this procedure code is to apply a discount to the new insert. The problem I'm having is too many records are being fetched. How would i fix this? do i use a trigger or a function?

Ok i have created a trigger but am i getting a PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following: := . ( @ % ;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHECK_DISCOUNT
AS

V_COUNT NUMBER;
V_C_NO APPOINTMENT.C_NO%TYPE;
V_BILL APPOINTMENT.BILL%TYPE;

BEGIN

SELECT C_NO,COUNT(C_NO)
INTO V_C_NO,V_COUNT
FROM APPOINTMENT
GROUP BY C_NO;

SELECT BILL
INTO V_BILL
FROM APPOINTMENT;

IF V_COUNT=3 THEN
V_BILL:=V_BILL * 0.9;
END IF;

UPDATE APPOINTMENT
SET BILL = V_BILL 
WHERE C_NO=:new.C_NO;
COMMIT;

END;
/

Create or replace TRIGGER CHECK_DISCOUNT 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF C_NO ON APPOINT     
FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE CURSOR C_APPTMENT IS 
SELECT C_NO,COUNT(C_NO) 
FROM APPOINTMENT GROUP BY C_NO; 

VISIT NUMBER; V_C_NO APPOINTMENT.C_NO%TYPE; 
V_BILL APPOINTMENT.BILL%TYPE; 
V_TEN NUMBER(3):=0.9; 

BEGIN 
   LOOP 
            OPEN C_APPTMENT; FETCH C_APPTMENT INTO V_C_NO, VISIT;
            EXIT WHEN C_APPTMENT%NOTFOUND; 

  SELECT BILL INTO V_BILL FROM APPOINTMENT; 
  IF VISITS =3 THEN V_BILL=V_BILL * V_TEN 
  WHERE :NEW.C_NO=V_C_NO; 
  UPDATE APPOINTMENT SET BILL:= V_BILL 
  WHERE:NEW.C_NO=V_C_NO; 
    END LOOP; 
      CLOSE C_APPTMENT;
```

END;

Comment: What are you trying to do? It's unclear if you want to update all rows, a subset of rows, or a single row.

Comment: This code *as is* is incorrect. You have `:new` which can only be used in a trigger. Please post an example which is at least syntactically correct (quite easy in Oracle: it compiles without error).

Comment: @VincentMalgrat i'm trying to update one row the newest

Comment: TRIGGER CHECK_DISCOUNT
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF C_NO ON APPOINT
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
CURSOR C_APPTMENT IS SELECT C_NO,COUNT(C_NO) FROM APPOINTMENT GROUP BY C_NO;
VISIT NUMBER;
V_C_NO APPOINTMENT.C_NO%TYPE;
V_BILL APPOINTMENT.BILL%TYPE;
V_TEN NUMBER(3):=0.9;
V_TWE NUMBER(3):= 0.8;
V_THR NUMBER(3):= 0.7;
BEGIN
LOOP
OPEN C_APPTMENT;
FETCH C_APPTMENT INTO V_C_NO, VISIT;EXIT WHEN C_APPTMENT%NOTFOUND;
SELECT BILL INTO V_BILL FROM APPOINTMENT;
IF VISITS =3 THEN V_BILL=V_BILL * V_TEN WHERE :NEW.C_NO=V_C_NO;
UPDATE APPOINTMENT
SET BILL:= V_BILL
WHERE:NEW.C_NO=V_C_NO;
END LOOP;
CLOSE C_APPTMENT;
END;

Comment: Above a trigger that applys a discount to the newest bill but getting  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the
 following:
 := . ( @ % ; @VincentMalgrat

Comment: @Colin'tHart check above

Comment: Please update your original question, don't paste huge wads of code as a comment.

Comment: @Colin'tHart sorry updated the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using select ... into you must assure you only select one row. 
Usually you will add a where clause with primary- or unique key columns. That way you are sure to select only one row. You will also have to provide for instances where no rows are selected. Add a exception handler to trap no_data_found exceptions

```
declare
   v_bill appointment.bill%type;
begin
   begin
      select a.bill
        into v_bill
        from appointment a
       where a.id = :my_id;  -- assuming ID is a primary key colomn
   exception
      when no_data_found then
         null;
   end;

   if v_bill is not null
   then
      --.. do something with v_bill
   end if;
end;
```